# Generalizing a function for an enum

Tags: enums, rust

I have an enum that looks like this

```
pub enum IpNetwork {
    V4(Ipv4Network),
    V6(Ipv6Network),
}
```

Each of those variants represents either a IPv4 or v6 CIDR. Now, `Ipv4Network` and `Ipv6Network` each has a method to get the prefix defined like this

```
// For Ipv4Network
pub fn prefix(&self) -> u8
// For Ipv6Network
pub fn prefix(&self) -> u128
```

How do I generalize the prefix method for the `IpNetwork` enum? I know that I can just have `u128` as the return type, but is that approach idiomatic?

Comment: If you really want to use `u8` and `u128` respectively, why not make an `pub enum Prefix { V4(u8), V6(u128) }` and return that instead?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a prefix function that operates on the `IpNetwork` type, but are unsure what the return type should be. Below is a possible approach you could follow.

### The argument against using an enum

As bheklilr mentioned in a comment, one of the alternatives is introducing an enum: `pub enum Prefix { V4(u8), V6(u128) }`.

This could make sense depending on your use case, but it seems like overkill to me here. In the end, you would end up pattern matching on the result of your generic `prefix` function. In that case, you could better pattern match on the `IpNetwork` object itself and call its corresponding `prefix` function.

## The case for `u128`

If you just want to obtain the integer value and don't need to differentiate between IPV4 and IPV6, returning an integer seems to be the way to go. A `u8` can be casted to `u128` without any problem and the overhead is negligible.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the standard library doesn't hold functionality for generic numeric types. You could, however, define a trait and implement it for `u8` and `u128`.
Also, there is the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate, which does basically that.